# Inlining JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

General JavaScript question here. It wasn't an easily googleable question (in my opinion) so I figured I'd ask it here to humans, and if it gets flagged as a duplicate then that's okay. It dawned on me while I was writing this function that there must be a way to write this in a way that doesn't rely on a temporary variable.

```
const isHex = num => {
  let result = true;
  [...num].map(n => { if (isNaN(parseInt(n,16))) result = false; });
  return result;
};
```

How would you inline a function like this and get rid of `result`? I feel like this is probably a gap in my JavaScript knowledge and I'm curious to know the answer. Maybe it's painfully obvious and this is a silly question. Idk.

Comment: You could use `.some()` instead of `.map()`.   It's not clear what you mean by the term "inline" here; usually that refers to what a language runtime might do to avoid making a function call.

Comment: Or `reduce` (although `some` is the right tool for the job here. `reduce` could be used if you wanted to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: `[...num]` is num a string? If it's an array, why would you use the spread operator on it?

Comment: Yea, I do. But the name `num` is misleading, then.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's supposed to be a string.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @FullStackJack. Naming variables can be tricky.

Comment: @cerbrus well its a string representing a `num`ber.

Comment: I guess `numStr` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and return early.

```js
const isHex = num => [...num].every(n => !isNaN(parseInt(n, 16)));
    
console.log(isHex('1a')); // true
console.log(isHex('1#')); // false
```

Same with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const isHex = num => ![...num].some(n => isNaN(parseInt(n, 16)));
    
console.log(isHex('1a')); // true
console.log(isHex('1#')); // false
```

Comment: This assumes `num` is an array of strings, which isn't exactly clear in the question. The code in the question suggests `num` isn't even an array.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. That's my point. The only logical input for the OP's code is a string of numeric characters, which is weird and requires clarification.

Comment: come on. op takes a spreadable object, this is not an array, because if so, it is superfluous to spred it into an array and do no make any mutation on it. even the (wrong) use of `map` shows that the values should not be changed. the only valid data structure, which is spreadable and not an array or an array like (which would not contain simple characters) is a string. at least the singular `num` suggests a single number.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Great answer Nina.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this

`isHex = num => (!![...num].filter(n => (isNaN(parseInt(n, 16)))).length);`